# Fastest way to reach level 99

Tags: chrono-trigger

I have recently bought *Chrono Trigger* for the virtual console on the Wii. I loved the game, got all the endings, but still don't have all my characters maxed to level **.

What is the fastest way that I can get XP for the characters?

Am I better off playing New Game+ multiple times or is there an area where there are high xp per kill monsters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try going to the **Black Omen.**

There are **three time periods** where you can go to there. **1,000 A.D.**, **600 A.D.**, and **12,000 B.C.** It's important to start with 1000 A.D. and make your way back, because if you beat the Black Omen in 12,000 B.C., it won't be there in 600 A.D. and 1,000 A.D. since you already beaten it (you've altered the future by changing the past!).

Once you've beaten all three Black Omens, you can stay in the last time period (12,000 BC) and fight random enemies inside -- making use of the first save point there. Just can move back and forth, save your game, and then go back for more.

As a side note, your inactive party members will only gain 3/4 EXP, but if they were to gain more than one level as the result of the EXP gained, they will only gain one level (no more EXP will be carried over).

Comment: The reverse chronological order of the Black Omen is very important!

Answer (score 0):

I would go in the Black Omen but first make sure you have a lot of Panceas to heal status' like poison, and sleep. Also a lot of Mid-Potions and Hi-Potions